# How to link those two pygame-menus

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, menu, pygame-menu

I have created two menus using Pygame-menu. The first one is the start menu (when you open the program).

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()

#Mida i nom de la finestra
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")

font = pygame_menu.font.FONT_8BIT
font1 = pygame_menu.font.FONT_NEVIS

menu = pygame_menu.Menu('Projecte MatZanfe', 600, 400,
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)

user_input = menu.add.text_input('User: ', font_name = font1, font_color = 'blue')
age_input = menu.add.text_input('Age: ', font_name = font1,font_color = 'Black')
menu.add.button('Start', font_name = font, font_color = 'green')
menu.add.button('Exit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT, font_name = font,font_color = 'red')
menu.mainloop(surface)
```

Then, the other one is a level selector.

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()

#Mida i nom de la finestra
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
#Logotip de la finestra
logotip = pygame.image.load("calculator.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(logotip)

font = pygame_menu.font.FONT_8BIT
font1 = pygame_menu.font.FONT_NEVIS
font2 = pygame_menu.font.FONT_BEBAS

menu = pygame_menu.Menu('Selecció dels mòduls', 600, 400,
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)

mixer.music.load('LevelSelector.wav')
mixer.music.play(-1)
menu.add.button('Sums', font_name = font2, font_color = 'green')
menu.add.button('Subtracts', font_name = font2, font_color = 'blue')
menu.add.button('Multiplications', font_name = font2,font_color = 'red')
menu.add.button('Divisions', font_name = font2, font_color = 'purple' )
menu.add.button("Back", font_name = font1, font_color = 'black')

menu.mainloop(surface)
```

How could I merge them, so when I press the "Start" button from the first menu, the whole surface displays the second menu but if I press the button "Back", it returns to the first menu? The files names are: Menu - Selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really familiar with this library, but I am guessing.

Check the [docs](https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.3/) here.

From the reference [here](https://github.com/ppizarror/pygame-menu/blob/8b941e2c561d511f8c3896c904800abfbdd527d1/pygame_menu/examples/game_selector.py#L249),

```py
# Import the required libraries
import pygame
import pygame_menu

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

# Make menu 2
menu2 = pygame_menu.Menu('Menu 2', 400, 300, theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_BLUE)
...

# Make main menu
menu = pygame_menu.Menu('Welcome', 400, 300, theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_BLUE)
...
menu.add.button('Menu2', menu2)
menu.add.button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

# Run your menu
menu.mainloop(surface)
```

You may assume the `surface` is your display surface.